# Read phone number from Tablet : Android

Tags: android

In my application I read device phone number as

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// Read phone number of device owner.
String phoneNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

where, this will work till device having phone application.

But when using device is a tablet(some tablet doesn't have phone application), then what will be the value of phoneNumber? Is it will null or blank String? Or it will be an error?

*I couldn't check it on emulator because SDK having Samsung Galaxy tab and that having Phone app.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this will work till device having phone application.

No, it will not. It is dependent upon what phone number was programmed into the SIM card. On some phones, this returns `null`. On my personal phone, it returns the wrong phone number. Do not rely upon `getLine1Number()` for much of anything.

> Is it will null or blank String?

I am reasonably certain that it will return `null`. It should not raise an `Exception`.

Comment: @user594955: Not that I am aware of. Bear in mind that a phone does not need to know its phone number in order to work, at least on GSM networks.